# marin-right on :last-of-type not working only in safari and iOS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

I've a horizontal slider with hero images. On iOS (and safari) it looks like the last image is not taking the margin-right from `margin-right: $custom-offset;` into account. **The second hero images should also be centered, same as the first hero image is doing.**

[image: first image]

[image: last image]

When i'm selecting the the first element and the flexbox of (.contract-slider) in the DOM, you see the following:

[image]

and when i go to the next element

[image]

My code is as follows:

```css
.custom-slider__container {
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-slider {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--custom-spacing-03);
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 241.5px;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

$custom-width: min(320px, 65%);
$custom-offset: calc(50% - ($custom-width / 2));

.custom-contract {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: $custom-width;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  scroll-snap-align: center;

  &:first-of-type {
    margin-left: $custom-offset;
  }

  &:last-of-type {
    margin-right: $custom-offset;
  }

  .custom-contract__content {
    user-select: none;
    transition: var(--custom-animation-timing-small) ease all;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }

  .custom-contract__image {
    aspect-ratio: 800 / 500;
  }

  &--active {
    transform: none;

    .custom-contract__content {
      transform: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-slider__container">
  <div
    ref="sliderContainer"
    class="custom-slider"
  >
    <div
      v-for="(customContract, index) in customContracts"
      :key="customContract.Id"
      :ref="($el) => { customContractRefs[customContract.Id] = $el }"
      class="custom-contract"
      :class="{
        'custom-contract--active':
          customContract.driverId === mostCenteredCustomContract
      }"
      :aria-label="custom-label"
      @click="doSomething()"
    >
      <div class="custom-contract__content">
        <img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've already tried the following

- changed `&:last-of-type` to `&:last-child`
- added a pseudo element after instead of `&:last-of-type`:

```
.contract::after {
  margin-right: $offset;
}
```

none of the above worked. Why is my margin-right not appearing? Is it because of how flexbox is working on safari/iOS?

Comment: Pretty sure it's related to `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Safari is not able to combine scroll snap with margins.

What you can do is add the margin to the container, using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo classess and some flexbox tricks. This means you can ditch the SCSS calculations.

```
.custom-slider::before,
.custom-slider::after {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  content: '';
}
```